# Xamarin.Android: OnResume called before OnCreate

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I understand that the android Activity life cycle says that OnCreate is always called first. But when I am debugging my application in Visual Studio 2015, the breakpoint in OnResume hits first and then it goes into OnCreate.

This is driving me crazy, it is a simple application. I have a launcher Activity called `StartScreen` and I am calling the `MainAcivity` in it's `OnResume`

StartScreen.cs "OnResume()"

```
Task startupWork = new Task(() => {
                Log.Debug(General.TAG, "Authenticate");
                applicationData = dataProvider.Retreive(General.DATA_PROVIDER_STRING);                
                Log.Debug(General.TAG, "Got authentication");
            });

startupWork.ContinueWith(t => {

                if (applicationData != null && applicationData.Any())
                {
                    Log.Debug(General.TAG, "Work is finished - Check connectivity.");


                    if(General.InternetConnected(this))
                        StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
                    else
                    {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        alert.SetTitle("Network Error");
                        alert.SetMessage("No network found, please check your internet connection.");
                        alert.SetPositiveButton("Ok", (senderAlert, args) => {

                        });
                        Dialog errorDialog = alert.Create();
                        errorDialog.Show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Debug(General.TAG, "Work is finished - start LoginActivity.");
                    StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(LoginActivity)));
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            startupWork.Start();
```

Now in my `MainActivity` I have only two empty methods for now

MainActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume()
}
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle) 
}
```

I have put breakpoints in both methods and always OnResume hits first. I can't understand why.

Am I doing something that's causing that?

Comment: what are you doing in the onResume() of base?

Comment: base.OnResume() is basically coming from Activity class which we have to extend on Android xamarin

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue, in my side it works fine. OnCreate --> OnStart--> OnResume.  You can recreate a new project and try again.

Comment: Although this is an old question I thought I would share for the benefit of future visitors: I thought I had similar behaviour but when I looked into it, `OnCreate()` was called and then there was a call to an external library which embedded a surface in the layout in my `OnCreate()` which interrupted it and resulted in a call to `OnResume()` before `OnCreate()` had finished. My break points were set near the end of `OnCreate()` so I didn't pick it up before!